# Is it possible to deliver modelstate errors to a different action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I am using two actions one for the get portion of my request (a generic looking url) and another for the post.

In the case that a post has ModelState errors, I would like to view to return to show the errors but I would like the url to be the generic url.

So this is what currently happens:

```
Get: http://foo.com/mycontroller  
Post: http://foo.com/mycontroller/specificviewaction (validation error occurs)  
Resultant url is: http://foo.com/mycontroller/specificviewaction
```

Where as I want it to be http://foo.com/mycontroller the appropriate errors.

Here is my current code:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // ... do stuff
        return View("specificviewaction ", model);
    }

    [HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult specificviewaction(Model model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        // ... do stuff
        }

        return View("specificviewaction", model);
    }
```

Note, there is no actual Index view, only specific views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.

I left the routing table as per the default implementation.

Then for each model type, I am putting a hidden field in the form with which type it is.

On the post, I check what type it is and use `TryUpdateModel` to update an instance of the model with the correct form values.

If it succeeds great, if not I can deliver the appropriate errors back.

I was trying to over think it, simplest approach was best.

Answer (score 0):

remove Index action - you don't need it.
Instead of this just add one more specificviewaction but for Get:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult specificviewaction()
{
    //do smth
    return View("specificviewaction", model);
}
```

and add the following router to Global.asax (before the default route):

```
routes.MapRoute("MyControllerRoute", // Route name
                "MyController/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "MyController", action = "specificviewaction", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults);
```

After this url "/MyController/" will be point to your "specificviewaction" by default.

Comment: that is kinda what i am trying to avoid, i want the user not to see the specifics but rather always the generic url.

Comment: which URL do you want to show? User will always see only "http://foo.com/mycontroller"

Comment: so.. with this decision user will always see only "foo.com/mycontroller". sorry - can't understand what's is wrong with this solution.

Comment: yes, basically i have multiple types that can be edited by a user, these are really just parts of the same system, to provide a better user experience, it will all appear to be of the same "type"